# Is there a way to get rid of this positional argument follows keyword argument?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

so im trying to fix this error;however, everytime I try to do something I get an positional argument follows a keyword argument error.

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
hist = model.fit(x=X_train, y=Y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=20, np.asarray(validation_split=0.2))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What do you mean, "Every time I try to do something"? Do what? Also, please post your error.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of np.asarray()

```
hist = model.fit(x=X_train, y=Y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=20, validation_split=0.2)
```